# How to make methods take in arrays from the main method?

Tags: java

What I need to do is make the main method give an array that the other two methods have.  The code works, but the numbers are just in the wrong place.

Everything I've tried has given me an exception and I'm not sure what to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    arrayTotalAndAverage(null); //not sure what to put in the parenthesis, it was corrected to be null
    arrayTwoDimTotalAndAverage(null);

}

public static void arrayTotalAndAverage(int[] array) {
    int[] numbers = {10, 4, 13, 29, 57, 92, 114, 212, 3, 88, 36, 101, 77, 42, 209}; //I need to move these numbers to the main method and I'm not sure how to leave it, is it "int[] numbers = {}"?

    int total = 0;
    double average = 0; //is this right?
    int highest = numbers[0];
    int lowest = numbers[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        total += numbers[i];
        average = total / numbers.length;

        if (numbers[i] > highest)
            highest = numbers[i];
        if (numbers[i] < lowest)
            lowest = numbers[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Total");
    System.out.println(total);

    System.out.println("Average");
    System.out.println(average);

    System.out.println("Highest number");
    System.out.println(highest);

    System.out.println("Lowest number");
    System.out.println(lowest);

}
```

---

```
public static void arrayTwoDimTotalAndAverage(int[][] array) {
    int[][] numbers = { { 11, 17, 24 }, { 49, 57, 78 }, { 677, 173, 923 } };

    int total = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int highest = numbers[0][0];
    int lowest = numbers[0][0];

    for (int row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numbers[row].length; col++) {
            total += numbers[row][col];
            average = total / numbers.length;

            if (numbers[row][col] > highest)
                highest = numbers[row][col];
            if (numbers[row][col] < lowest)
                lowest = numbers[row][col];
        }

    }
    System.out.println("2D Total");
    System.out.println(total);

    System.out.println("2D Average");
    System.out.println(average);

    System.out.println("2D Highest number");
    System.out.println(highest);

    System.out.println("2D Lowest number");
    System.out.println(lowest);
}
```

Comment: *"Everything I've tried has given me an exception"* Post the exception stack trace. For better help sooner post a proper [mre] and indent your code correctly (and post it here as code-formatted text). Extra spaces before or after curly-braces are just not necessary so avoid it.

Comment: The answers below explain how to pass integer arrays as arguments, which was your original question - you may also want to look into how you're calculating `average` in each of these methods; you're using integer division when you probably want to use floating-point division.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of how to send an array and receive them from another place is like this:

We have our array outside, then you pass it as parameter to your method, where you're expecting an `int[] parameter`, then you can make use of it with `parameter` variable name inside that method.

For example:

```
public class ArrayAsParametersExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        
        printNumbersFromArray(numbers);
    }
    
    private static void printNumbersFromArray(int numbersArray[]) {
        for (int n : numbersArray) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me? I don't get what's your premise on this. Please explain @pkm as well as your code in your answer.

Comment: I am flagging your response, cause I suppose you have multiple stackoverflow accounts. If that's not the case then moderators will remove the flag.

Comment: Cool! @pkm Can you explain what makes you think I have multiple accounts? I don't but I want to know what made you think this? A downvote I made in your answer for not describing what changed in your code from OP's code? The comment I made after? Why did you delete your previous comment stating "I suppose you have multiple stack overflow accounts?" It doesn't give me enough information on why you think so, or how I can improve my answer because of the downvote.

Comment: @pkm On what evidence do you claim that Frakcool has multiple accounts? And why would that require you to flag his response?

Answer (score 0):

Like all Java objects, arrays are passed by value ... but the value is the reference to the array. So, when you assign something to a cell of the array in the called method, you will be assigning to the same array object that the caller sees.

So Instead of defining the array in each method, we can initialize the array in the main method, which we can then pass to the candidate methods as a parameter.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] numbers = {10, 4, 13, 29, 57, 92, 114, 212, 3, 88, 36, 101, 77, 42, 209}; 
int[][] numbers2 = { { 11, 17, 24 }, { 49, 57, 78 }, { 677, 173, 923 } };
    arrayTotalAndAverage(numbers); 
    arrayTwoDimTotalAndAverage(numbers2);

}

public static void arrayTotalAndAverage(int[] numbers) {

    int total = 0;
    double average = 0; //is this right?
    int highest = numbers[0];
    int lowest = numbers[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        total += numbers[i];
        average = total / numbers.length;

        if (numbers[i] > highest)
            highest = numbers[i];
        if (numbers[i] < lowest)
            lowest = numbers[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Total");
    System.out.println(total);

    System.out.println("Average");
    System.out.println(average);

    System.out.println("Highest number");
    System.out.println(highest);

    System.out.println("Lowest number");
    System.out.println(lowest);

}
public static void arrayTwoDimTotalAndAverage(int[][] numbers) {

    int total = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int highest = numbers[0][0];
    int lowest = numbers[0][0];

    for (int row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numbers[row].length; col++) {
            total += numbers[row][col];
            average = total / numbers.length;

            if (numbers[row][col] > highest)
                highest = numbers[row][col];
            if (numbers[row][col] < lowest)
                lowest = numbers[row][col];
        }

    }
    System.out.println("2D Total");
    System.out.println(total);

    System.out.println("2D Average");
    System.out.println(average);

    System.out.println("2D Highest number");
    System.out.println(highest);

    System.out.println("2D Lowest number");
    System.out.println(lowest);
}
```

Comment: Please explain the code, code-only answers don't help OP or future readers to understand what the changes in the code were or how your code works and why.

Comment: Alright so this was pretty close, I figured that the problem was I needed to remove the one line where I tried defining the numbers and I replaced all the numbers with array instead.  It works great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `main` function look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  int[] numbers = {10, 4, 13, 29, 57, 92, 114, 212, 3, 88, 36, 101, 77, 42, 209};
  arrayTotalAndAverage(numbers);
}
```

And do similarly for your other method.

Answer (score 0):

Change `arrayTwoDimTotalAndAverage` like this.

```
public static void arrayTwoDimTotalAndAverage(int[][] array) {
    int[][] numbers = { { 11, 17, 24 }, { 49, 57, 78 }, { 677, 173, 923 } };

    int total = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int highest = numbers[0][0];
    int lowest = numbers[0][0];
    int count = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numbers[row].length; col++) {
            total += numbers[row][col];
            count += numbers[row].length;

            if (numbers[row][col] > highest)
                highest = numbers[row][col];
            if (numbers[row][col] < lowest)
                lowest = numbers[row][col];
        }

    }
    average = total / count;
    System.out.println("2D Total");
    System.out.println(total);

    System.out.println("2D Average");
    System.out.println(average);

    System.out.println("2D Highest number");
    System.out.println(highest);

    System.out.println("2D Lowest number");
    System.out.println(lowest);
}
```